# How to order by a table based on the other tables column

Tags: sql-order-by, sybase

i have 2 tables

```
Table 1 
col1  col2
----  ----
BLANK  A
D      A
V      A
BLANK  B
D      B
V      B

Table 2 
col1  col2  sex  age
----  ----  ---- ----
A     as     M    45
A     sa     F    32
A     asd    F    45 
B     as     M    45
B     sa     F    32
B     asd    F    45
```

my output should be in a order like for each value in col1 of Table 1 should be repeated with the Table2 values and that to in the order and in the second table it should be ordered by Sex and for Female records alone we need to order them by age older first. finally the output table should look like below.

```
COL1  COL2 COL3 SEX AGE
---- ----- ---- --- ---
BLANK  A   as   M   45
BLANK  A   asd  F   45
BLANK  A   sa   F   32
D      A   as   M   45
D      A   asd  F   45
D      A   sa   F   32
V      A   as   M   45
V      A   asd  F   45
V      A   sa   F   32
BLANK  B   as   M   45
BLANK  B   asd  F   45
BLANK  B   sa   F   32
D      B   as   M   45
D      B   asd  F   45
D      B   sa   F   32
V      B   as   M   45
V      B   asd  F   45
V      B   sa   F   32
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the rows repeating for each value without any join criteria, something like this should do (although I don't have Sybase to test on, it's fairly straight forward SQL);

```sql
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2 AS col3, sex, age
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
ORDER BY t1.col1, sex DESC, age DESC
```

[An SQL Server SQLfiddle as a sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac9d4/6).

EDIT: After your edited question, I assume you want to pair `t1.col2` with the corresponding `t2.col1`, then this ordering should be the correct one;

```sql
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2 AS col3, sex, age
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.col2 = t2.col1
ORDER BY t1.col2, t1.col1, sex DESC, age DESC
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/24500/1).

Comment: but it will not come in the exact order i mentioned it is displaying in order of sex and age alone properly . but my main criteria is ordering based on the t1.col1

Comment: @Ramesh Could you point out where in the SQLfiddle the order is wrong? I can't see the difference from your desired result.